# class create another class and associate with it later delete it, how to show it in UML class diagram?

Tags: class, uml, associations, ooad

Let A and B are classes.

- A is the class which is responsible for creating class B
- after creating of ,B A is associated with B
- after some time class A is Delete class B

as a example for above scenario consider
there is project manager and he is responsible for creating,editing,deleting project from the system

i know class A create class b can show in UML as dependency relationship

i have two questions

1. how to represent class delete another class
2. so there is both association and dependency relationship from A to B.
   How should this relationship be demonstrated on UML class diagram? Should I use booth association(straight line) and dependency(dashed line) relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply put a multiplicity of `0..1` towards the association to `B`. And that's it. No extra dependency.

Comment: class delete another class is that also a dependancy

Comment: delete is an operation. That's behavior shown in a SD.

Comment: It seems that A manage the lifecycle of B (instantation and deletion) so the association is more a composition than a "simple" association.

Comment: @granier Definitely not. If A composes B then B will die wit A. That's not a requirement here.

Comment: "after some time class A is Delete class B"